# Использование enum: ошибка типов

Tags: java

Вот мой enum (лежит в классе Segment)

```
public static enum Income {
    A("A"),
    B("B"),
    C("C");

    private String value;

    Income(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Допустим, у меня есть  переменная String = "А". Как написать метод, который вернул бы значение энума Income.A?

```
int r;
Segment.Age qew = Segment.Age.valueOf("В");
if ( qew == Segment.Income.B ) { r = 1; } else { r = 100500;}
out.println(r);
```

Дописал вот такой код. По идее должен вывести 1, не так ли?

================================================

```
Public class Segment{
public static enum Age implements SegmentValue{
    AGE1("-18"),
    AGE2("19-24"),
    AGE3("25-34"),
    AGE4("35-44"),
    AGE5("45+");

    private String value;

    Age(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }

    public static Age valOf(String str) {
        for (Age a : Age.values()) {
            if (a.toString().equals(str)) {
                return a;
            }
            out.println("Значение не соответствует возможному значению возраста");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

}

Метод ругается на то, что возвращаемый результат не типа `Segment.Age`.

Comment: у вас первый код и второй не связан между собой

Comment: Да, не связан - второй кусок из void main(String[] args)

Comment: А при чем тут `Segment.Age`, если мы говорили про `Segment.Income`?

Comment: Призываю в тред @Barmaley-я и устраняюсь. Может быть, он вас поймет.

> Метод ругается на то, что возвращаемый результат не типа Segment.Age

Странно, у меня собирается. И, да, вынесите `throw ...` из тела цикла.

Comment: Вы читали про энумы статью Джошуа Блоха? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html Я надеюсь, что она вам ОЧЕНЬ поможет. Эта же статья одна из глав в книге "Effective Java". Очень советую.

Comment: Минусую @Stas0n - всю конфу уже заср*л своими постами про `enum` - неужели нельзя прочитать один раз главку в книжке?! Пока не научится нормально ставить вопросы и принимать ответы в игнор!

Answer (score 1):

Например так (я предполагаю, что имя объекта перечисляемого типа не обязательно соответствует строковому значению):

```
public static enum Income {

    A("111"), B("222"), C("333");

    private String value;

    Income(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }

    public static Income valOf(String str) {
        for (Income i : Income.values()) {
            if (i.toString().equals(str)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Comment: а что такое Planet?

Comment: Мне бы решение для конкретной задачи, т.е. когда имя объекта перечисляемого типа соответствует строковому значению

Comment: Planet - это вечерний тупняк. Обновил.

Comment: > когда имя объекта перечисляемого типа соответствует 

Тогда зачем строковое значение?

Допустим у вас есть `enum Income { A, B, C }`. Вы всегда можете получить значение по названию:

    Income i = Income.valueOf("A");

И наименование по значению:

    String str = Income.A.toString();

Comment: Метод же должен возвращать результат типа Segment.Income (enum лежит в классе Segment)
Как это сделать?

Comment: Простите. Я не понимаю, чего вы хотите. Я вам привел совершенно валидный код. У вас есть класс `Segment`, внутри перечисляемый тип `Income`. Внутри класса `Segment` вы можете обращаться к нему как к `Income`, а не `Segment.Income`.

Comment: PS. Не в обиду будет сказано: напротяжении ваших последних вопросов, создается впечатление, что вы, не до конца поняв принципы работы инструмента (классы, перечисления, generic-и), пытаетесь смоделировать предметную область, о которой никто из присутствующих не имеет представления. Поэтому либо вам стоит подтянуть матчасть по книгам, либо посвятить нас в то, что вы пытаетесь сваять.

Comment: Пардон, вечерний тупняк)

Comment: А вот что-то с ситуацией, когда имя объекта перечисляемого типа не соответствует строковому значению - косяк.
см. исправления.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

Он у вас уже написан в методе toString()

Comment: добавил правку. Что там не так?